# WP Query to Get Array of Slugs

Tags: posts, wp-query

So I will be using a template where posts have related products (woocommerce) as defined in the custom fields. I've just got a load of slugs and I dunno how I can query the array of slugs. Heres what i've got:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $products_used
    )
);
```

I know you could do it with IDs but I need this done with slugs. Is it possible with WP_Query or should I just write the query myself to save stress?

Comment: [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) should be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Just run a normal `tax_query` and set the `field` parameter to `slug` in the query. I assume that you already have a way getting the array of slugs

(*Requires PHP5.4+*)

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query'      => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'TAXONOMY_NAME',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => ['something', 'something-again', 'something-else'],
        ]
    ],
];
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### EDIT

From comments, these slugs are in actual fact post slugs and not term slugs. In this case, you will need to query posts with `get_page_by_path()`. You will need to have an array of slugs and then use a `foreach` loop to query the posts

You can try the following: (*Just make sure the post type is correct, I have used `product` here*)

```
$slugs_array = ['something', 'something-again', 'something-else'];
foreach ( $slugs_array as $v ) {
    $post = get_page_by_path( $v, OBJECT, 'product' );
    // If we don't have a valid post object, continue
    if ( !$post ) 
        continue;

    // Setup postdata to make template tags available   
    setup_postdata( $post );

    the_title();
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Yea I have the slugs in an array already, what would the taxonomy name be though?

Comment: If it is the default Woocommerce taxonomy, then it should be `product_cat` if I'm sure (haven't worked with Woocommerce :-))

Comment: I have amended my original post with the new code I am using. It's showing every products (up to 12 posts) not the slugs from $products_used... I'm also using the old array syntax for compatibility issues

Comment: `$products_used`, is it term slugs or post slugs, a `tax_query` sometimes returns all posts regardless if invalid terms are passed to it

Comment: I just realised, it's not supposed to be looking at the category slugs, it's supposed to be the product slugs so taxonomy would be useless here.

Comment: See my update. Should work now

Comment: Lovely, that's how I was originally going to do it but it seemed kinda long having to do multiple queries, I thought there might have been a better way of doing it

Comment: No, there isn't much you can do with post slugs. This is about the best you are going to get natively :-)